# How to configure log4r for logstash

Tags: logstash, log4r

Someone please show me an example of log4r configuration for sending logs to logstash. My rails application lies in a remote server.

Also logstash configuration for recieving log4r logs.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat). A tool by the creators of logstash that allow you to send logs from one server to another with logstash or elasticsearch. The application is very lightweight and simple to configure.

Here is an example configuration that sends the content of **/path/to/your/logfile.log** to a logstash server name **logstashserver**:

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
        - /path/to/your/logfile.log
      input_type: log
  registry_file: /var/lib/filebeat/registry

output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ["logstashserver:5043"]

shipper:
logging:
  files:
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760 # = 10MB
```

If you need a more comprehensive guide check this [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/12/configuring-logstash-filebeat.html)

Greetings,

Comment: I tried with filebeat. Since my rails application is in a remote ubuntu machine, I gave my public IP address for logstash hosts.

Comment: In my router I forwarded my logstash ip and port with public ip and port.
But still logs are not found in logserver.

Comment: Have you checked your logstash listening port? Please, post your logstash configuration

Comment: Finally I got it. my logstash config file is almost same as your recommended link. The only difference is I used tcp plugin instead of beats. 
Thnk u so much

Comment: That's great news Babeesh. Would you mind to check my answer as correct?